# Dynamic grid items not matching CSS styling

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a dynamic CSS styled grid where the user can add and delete entries which under the hood are wrapped into containers (for ease of creation and deletion).

However, I'm trying to style the grid so that the input box and `delete` buttons span a number of rows respectively and I can't get them to work.

I've added colour to the header and content containers to try and find where I'm going wrong, noting that colour isn't appearing for the content container.

I'm also wondering if this has to do with the way I've set this up dynamically, whereby I'm not creating a division at any point in the `addFields` function which you would usually do when adding grid-items. Instead I'm just appending child items, could this be the reason I'm not seeing the styling I'm after, in that appending these items actually bypasses or ignores the grid container styling completely?

Or perhaps appending new grid for each input row is why this is breaking (and is most likely a very strange/poor way of doing this!)

Thank you for any hints as to why the styling isn't working!

Here is a stripped down version of the script I'm using:

```js
var row = 1;

function addFields() {
  row++;

  var container = document.getElementById("content_container");

  var inner_container = document.createElement("div");
  inner_container.class = "grid-container-content";
  inner_container.id = "inner_container_" + row;

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.id = "input_" + row;
  input.type = "text";
  input.placeholder = "Insert goal";
  input.classList.add("input", "item2");
  inner_container.appendChild(input);

  var button = document.createElement("button");
  button.id = "button_" + row;
  button.classList.add("item3");
  button.innerText = "delete item";
  button.onclick = function() {
    inner_container.remove();
  }
  inner_container.appendChild(button);

  container.appendChild(inner_container);
}
```

```css
.grid-container-head {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
  gap: 50px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.item1 {
  grid-column: 3 / span 1;
}

.grid-container-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
  gap: 50px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.item2 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
}

.item3 {
  grid-column: 4 / span 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="grid-container-head" id="header_container">
    <button class="button item1" id="button_1" type="button" onclick="addFields()">Add new item</button><br>
  </div>

  <div class="container" id="content_container" </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you mark-baijens for the question edits, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner container was not displayed as a grid. That is because you incorrectly added the class `grid-container-content` to the container. You will need to add a class using [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) like you did with your input and button:

`inner_container.classList.add("grid-container-content");`.

See this example below.

```js
var row = 1;

function addFields() {
  row++;

  var container = document.getElementById("content_container");

  var inner_container = document.createElement("div");
  inner_container.classList.add("grid-container-content");
  inner_container.id = "inner_container_" + row;

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.id = "input_" + row;
  input.type = "text";
  input.placeholder = "Insert goal";
  input.classList.add("input", "item2");
  inner_container.appendChild(input);

  var button = document.createElement("button");
  button.id = "button_" + row;
  button.classList.add("item3");
  button.innerText = "delete item";
  button.onclick = function() {
    inner_container.remove();
  }
  inner_container.appendChild(button);

  container.appendChild(inner_container);
}
```

```css
.grid-container-head {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
  gap: 50px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.item1 {
  grid-column: 3 / span 1;
}

.grid-container-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
  gap: 50px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.item2 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
}

.item3 {
  grid-column: 4 / span 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="grid-container-head" id="header_container">
    <button class="button item1" id="button_1" type="button" onclick="addFields()">Add new item</button><br>
  </div>

  <div class="container" id="content_container" </div>
</body>
```

**Note:** you could use the `className` property too which corresponds to the html `class` attribute. This can assign the class(es) as a string. However I would recommend to always use `classList` for better controllability of the classes on the element.

Comment: Oh man I was so close! Thanks so much, that was a quick fix!